# Including external stylesheets in a PHP file

Tags: php, html, css

```
<link href="/app/app.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
```

The above is the code I'm using to access a stylesheet, but it's not working at the .

Some extra details:
This is in a `.php` file, but it's located within the head of an `html` section
I'm working on a temporary url (i.e. 'my.ipa.dd.res/mydomain.com/dir/'). This might be the reason it's not working.

Edit:
It's a stylesheet I'd like to use on several pages, which is why I'm trying to point to a root directory (so that I don't need the file in every single folder I create).

Comment: When you use slash in start of href, that mean start href path from root of site. Your problem can solve by this. You must use slash in start of href and write path of css file after it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Website styling not being applied. (Calling stylesheet.css from a php include)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34556931/website-styling-not-being-applied-calling-stylesheet-css-from-a-php-include)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you remove the leading slash it will look for the css file in the folder relative to the current.

```
<link href="app/app.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
```

Edit: to reuse in multiple scripts in different dirs you would need to specify an absolute path, so to avoid having to change it in multiple places when you go live (ie stop using the temporary url) you should define a variable.

```
<?php
// set absolute path to the stylesheet
$cssPath = 'http://my.ipa.dd.res/mydomain.com/dir/';
?>
```

And

```
<link href="<?php echo $cssPath; ?>app/app.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
```

Depending on your php architecture you may need to define `$cssPath` as a global or you may be able to add it to an existing config variable. This is completely dependent on your framework.

Comment: Thanks Tristan, but I was a bit unclear in my original post. I do want to keep the file in a root directory so that I can use it on several pages without creating new versions of the file.

Answer (score 1):

Well I think you need to store your root directory path as a string to include your css file with an absolute URL. 
Something like :

```
<link href="{$absoluteRootPath}/css/styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
```

Comment: We need more information to help him solve his problem.

Comment: Yes, but this isn't an answer.

Comment: Well yes, sorry, I can't comment anything.

Comment: I've added some more info to the OP

Answer (score 0):

I've been having this same problem recently. Here's what worked for me

Now on the index page, replace **link rel="/app/app.css" href="stylesheet" type="text/css"**

with

**?php include 'style.php' ?**

And on the style.php page insert the following tags:

**style and /style**

You can put the regular CSS between those two tags. See if that works. BTW for some reason I can't insert the greater or less than symbols without making the code disappear... Forgive me, I'm new here..