# Website styling not being applied. (Calling stylesheet.css from a php include)

Tags: php, css, web

I wonder whether anyone could help me resolve some problems I'm having in creating a website using HTML, CSS...and PHP for the first time. (My previous attempts at web design were only in HTML and CSS).

The problem at present is that my home-page (`index.php`) somehow isn't 'seeing' my `stylesheet.css`.

The code for the `index.php` is basically as follows :

```
    <?php
      $page_title='Home';
      [php-code here, to call in include1.php.....Please see below for details]
    ?>
    <div class="copy">
      [page content here, in html]
    </div>
   <?php
      [php-code here, to call in include2.php.....Please see below for details]
?>
```

My folder structure is :
web

```
   css
     stylesheet.css
   images
     logo.png
   includes
     include1.php
     include2.php
   index.php
```

In attempting to call in `include1.php` (containing doc type declaration, and Head section including reference to `stylesheet.css`), I've tried the following (inserted between `<?php` and `?>`, as shown above), all without success :

```
$pathtoinclude1 = $_SERVER]'DOCUMENT_ROOT'];
$pathtoinclude1 .= "/includes/include1.php";
include_once($pathtoinclude1);
```

and

```
include('/includes/include1.php')
```

In `include1.php`, my reference to the `stylesheet.css` is :

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/stylesheet.css" media="Screen" type="text/css"/>
```

When I preview the home-page, all I get is the text in default font (Times New Roman?). None of the styling via CSS is being applied.

Can anyone give me some pointers as to what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Correction :  $pathtoinclude1 = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];      (Error in my message only, and not my code. I still have my css styling problem).

Comment: try `href="css/stylesheet.css"` instead of `href="../css/stylesheet.css"` in include1.php

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, Zoltan. Unfortunately, that doesn't fix the problem.

Comment: OK.. then just press `Ctrl + U` to see the source of the page. Look what is the generated path to your CSS file and adjust it

Comment: I've done that (used Ctrl + U to view the source code), and the only code showing is the code within include1.php. The html code I've included in index.php is not showing ??

Comment: that doesn't make any sense. Even if you're using frames viewing the source should display the index page

Comment: Using the code below is starting to give me some desirable styling results. It seems I may have made had some coding error (not quite pinpointed what it was, though!) between the head tags in include1.php

In index.php :
<?php
$pathtoinclude1 = $_SERVER]'DOCUMENT_ROOT'];
$pathtoinclude1 .= "/includes/include1.php";
include_once($pathtoinclude1);
?>

In include1.php :
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/stylesheet.css" media="Screen" type="text/css"/>

Comment: $_SERVER]'DOCUMENT_ROOT']; is wrong. It should be  $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];

Comment: Thank you all for your input. However, despite my various attempts, this is unresolved. I'm trying the following within index.php :   <?php   $page_title='Home';     $root=$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];    $includes=$root.'/includes/';   include($includes/'include1.php');  ?>    However, yet again, index.php is not 'seeing' include1.php

Answer (score 1):

If that first answer doesn't work, try replacing

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/stylesheet.css" media="Screen" type="text/css">
```

with `<?php include 'style.php'?>`

And then in the style.php file include the `<style>` tags and then add the css regularly.

Answer (score 0):

1. Since you say you are using `php` for the first time, make sure you have the correct  `html` declaration.

although you have already worked with `html,css` just a reminder:

```
<?php
      $page_title='Home';
      [php-code here, to call in include1.php.....Please see below for details]
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <!-- MAKE SURE YOU'RE INCLUDING THE
  EXTERNAL CSS FILE HERE BUT NOT TO INCLUDE YOUR PHP INCLUDES!
  WHICH ACCORDING TO YOUR FILE STRUCTURE SHOULD BE -->
<link rel="stylesheet" 
      href="../css/stylesheet.css" 
      media="Screen" 
      type="text/css"/>
</head>
<body>
<div class="copy">
      [page content here, in html]
    </div>
   <?php
      [php-code here, to call in include2.php.....Please see below for details]
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

When you `include()` the file from `index.php`, the path looks like:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/stylesheet.css" media="Screen" type="text/css"/>
```

This path is going one directory back from `index.php` which is not a valid path. Your path in `include1.php` should look like this when you include it in `index.php`:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/stylesheet.css" media="Screen" type="text/css">
```

Also, if CSS includes properly but styles still do not show up, try removing browser cache.

Answer (score -1):

Try this.  It worked for me

Let's assume that you CSS file is named 'css.css'

And it is located in the same directory with you home page.

Just add this at the head tag:

```
Head
Style
<?php include('css.css') ?>
style
head
```

Don't forget to add corresponding tags