# Include an external CSS file in PHP

Tags: php, html, css

I have a testing website that I'm using for pulling data from SQL. I've got the connection to SQL working and now I'm trying to style the tables that I'm creating. I cannot load the external CSS file though. I've tried several different things that I've found here such as:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>QDef</title>

    <link rel="StyleSheet" href="StyleSheet.css" type="text/css">
</head>
<body>
```

and this:

```
<?php
    $servername = "ServerName";
    $username = "User";
    $password = "Password";
    $dbname = "DBName";
    echo '<link rel="StyleSheet" href="StyleSheet.css" type="text/css">';
    try
```

Neither way is working. I have several tables that I create based on buttons that I push on the main page and each one is pulling from different tables in the DB and I use a different PHP file for each so that I don't get them confused. so I'd like to have just the one CSS file that will style all of the tables. I have ID's for each table so that I can style them individually if I wanted to, but I can't get the CSS to load into the PHP file.

Any help would be appreciated.

**EDIT**
All files are in the same directory on my computer:
Documents/My Web Sites/ EmptySite
[image]

**EDIT 2**
Here is the Main Page:
[image]

and here is one of the table query pages that I'm trying to add the CSS in:
[image]

Comment: check for  pathname  ..

Comment: How isn't it working?  Does the file exist at the path you think it does?  Do you get 404s?

Comment: Are you sure that the file isn't loading?  Perhaps it is loading but the contents aren't being applied to your elements correctly?

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem. The URL is either wrong or you have a permissions problem (or the CSS is wrong)

Comment: The question is not clear. You shall provide directory structure so that we can check that if you are including CSS file correct or not.

Comment: The files are all in the same directory. This is on my computer so there aren't any issues with permissions. I get no error codes the tables simply don't format based on what I have in the CSS file. I have several different things that should be working like: `border-collapse: collapse;`

Comment: Do you have any other files like Javascript files that work for you>>

Comment: Paste your directory Screenshot here  in question that will be good to understand and write your CSS content rules for things that are not working

Comment: You are not including CSS in php.
You are writing a link in the resulting html, so the browser can include it.
This should be debugged in your browser.
Use ctrl-V or whatever appropriate to view the html-source (Not the php which creates it)
The see if you can load the css by clicking on the links in the source.

Comment: I have the main page that uses an iFrame then shows the tables in the iFrame, but there are no other files that are external that are working other than the PHP files that I want to have the CSS included in.

Comment: Press Ctrl+U and then view source, try clicking on CSS file in source code in browser and see if you are getting file right

Comment: When I press Ctrl+U there are no links to click on. It just shows the HTML code from the main page as shown above in the second edit

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Website styling not being applied. (Calling stylesheet.css from a php include)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34556931/website-styling-not-being-applied-calling-stylesheet-css-from-a-php-include)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've been having this same problem recently. Here's what worked for me:

On the index page, replace

```
link rel="StyleSheet" href="StyleSheet.css" type="text/css"
```

with

```
<?php include 'style.php' ?>
```

And on the style.php page insert the tags `style` and `/style`

You can put the regular CSS between those two tags. See if that works.

Comment: This does not work for me. I've updated the main page with the PHP include, but then that page no longer works.

Comment: What I ended up doing was adding a `Class` to each of the `<tr></tr>` and then alternating the names so that one is `row1` and the next is `row2` and back and forth. Then in the CSS I just added a background for the rows that makes them different from each other like this:`.row {background-color: #e5e5e5}`

Answer (score 1):

After stopping and restarting the website some of the CSS styles are working. I have the `hover` working so that the rows change background color when the mouse hovers over them. The `Border-collapse: collapse` is still not working though. I appreciate the help that was given.

What made this work is adding the `echo <link rel="StyleSheet" href="StyleSheet.css" type="text/css">` in the PHP lines of the code instead of in the HTML at the top.

One other thing, @Gags mentioned writing the CSS content rules. I don't know what that means, I'm new to css and php/html. If you could add a link to documentation I would appriciate it.